# cdrom is not mounted but it is present

Tags: centos-6

With the `wodim` command, I can see cdrom on Centos-6. However, when I try to mount the cdrom, I get an error. I have to say the disk is not empty and I can see the content on another computer.

```
$ wodim --devices
wodim: Overview of accessible drives (1 found) :
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  dev='/dev/scd0'     rwrw-- : 'TSSTcorp' 'CDDVDW TS-L633F'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
# mount -t iso9660 -o ro /dev/scd0 /mnt/cdrom/
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0
```

Any thought?

Comment: There is `/dev/sr0` in the response although you're trying to mount `/dev/scd0`. Please verify it's really so.

Comment: Got the same error